# Identifying case insensitive file and folder conflicts

Tags: ext4, exfat

I'm making a backup of an EXT4 system on an exfat partition. The EXT4 system has identical names with different cases, for instance Video, and VIDEO. Is there any way to find and identify all the possible conflicts?

Right now rsync first uploads one directory and then basically deletes all its contents (when using the --delete option)

Comment: "EXT4 system on an exfat partition" don't. Not only filenames will clash but you will also mess up permissions. Use the same filesystems or one that includes all of the features as what the original is on (so you can use ext4 to backup files on a fat32; not the other way). Only exception would be using 1 tar file to store all your files into it.

Comment: It is a bad idea to back up an ext4 system to an exfat partition this way.

Comment: @Rinzwind I know the mantra, but the problem is I need the backup to be accessible from windows...

Comment: Then you will need to prepare your Linux for that: No files/dirs with the same name on the same level and windows will destroy the permissions on those files. Not a problem with videofiles but is is for executables. You wlll need to reset those each time you put them back on Linux. Windows filesystems are just not as versatile.